# String formatting in scala

Tags: scala, string-formatting

I am looking for a string format solution in Scala. I have the below string:

```
str =  {"card_id" : %s,"cust_id": %s,"card_info": {"card_type" : "%s","credit_limit": %s},"card_dates" : [{"date":"%s" },{"date":"%s" }]}
```

And here I want to replace `"%S"` with string value. Is there any function in Scala so that I can apply that function and get the proper result?

I have tried `string.format("%s", str, arrayofvalue)` but it's not giving the proper result.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use:

```
val str = """{"card_id" : %s,"cust_id": %s,"card_info": {"card_type" : "%s","credit_limit": %s},"card_dates" : [{"date":"%s" },{"date":"%s" }]}"""
str.format(arrayofvalue:_*)
```

Note that I have use `"""` for using double quote in `str` as literal.

Answer (score 1):

In scala you can do this

```
val i = 123
val s = " a string"

val str = s"Here's$s $i" // result: Here's a string 123
```

Answer (score 0):

Scala provides several ways of string interpolation.

## s"" - String Interpolator

```
s"$var text ${var.func}"
```

see http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html

## String.format

Scala also supports the `.format`method on strings

```
scala> "%s - %d".format("test", 9)
res5: String = test - 9
```

http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-string-formatting-java-string-format-method

## Using a JSON lib

As you are creating `JSON` here you should use on of the many `JSON` libraries like

- JSON4s http://json4s.org/
- Spray JSON https://github.com/spray/spray-json
- Play JSON

This will give you much more safety for this task than string interpolation.