# Passing Parameters at run time for spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am trying to run the spark scala program which will read hive data and load into postgres table.

```scala
val ds = args(0)

//Getting current time of system
val ldt1 = LocalDateTime.now

val df2 = hiveContext.sql("select * from hive.table where ds='${ds}'")
df2.write .mode(SaveMode.Append) .jdbc( url = url, table = "post.tabl1", connectionProperties = connectionProperties)

//Getting current time of system
val ldt2 = LocalDateTime.now
```

Through Spark shell i am giving as below:

```scala
data=20181210
```

/usr/hdp/2.5.3.0-37/spark2/bin/spark-submit --class abc --master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 10G --executor-memory 10G --num-executors 30  --jars xyz.jar  prq.jar $data

I tried all ways like giving `${data}` even i changed `data='20181210'` but nothing is working.

Even i need time difference between `ldt2 - ldt1` which is not giving.

Could you please advise on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String formatting in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37002294/string-formatting-in-scala)

Comment: still not working

Comment: Please advise on the time difference.

Comment: Please check the below answer about how to pass parameters. Please elaborate what you need in the time difference.

Comment: I am looking for time difference in hours . i.e before start of the df2 and and after write. i..e ldt2 - ldt1.

Answer (score 0):

Check below simple example for what you need

```
object Main{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val ds = args(0)

    println("Args 1 passed is " + ds)

  }
}
```

You can package this program using any tool maven for example and run the below command

```
spark-submit --class Main --master local[*] --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 1G --executor-memory 1G --num-executors 1 TestLogic-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 12345
```

Sample Output

```
2019-01-04 05:34:02 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop lib
rary for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Args 1 passed is 12345
2019-01-04 05:34:03 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
2019-01-04 05:34:03 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory C:\Users\Path
```